# How to set range for contour matlab

Tags: matlab, contour

As far as I know, I can set number of contour lines, but they will be distributed evenly from min value to max value(for example, from 0.4 to 2.3). How can I set range for contour lines from 0.54 to 1.7 with step 0.04?

I use that function like that `contour(x,y,po,20,'LineColor',[0 0 0]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the actual levels at which you want to draw the contours  as the [fourth input argument](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) rather than the number of contours.

```
contour(x, y, po, 0.54:0.04:1.7, 'LineColor', [0 0 0])
```

> `contour(X,Y,Z,v)` draws a contour plot of matrix `Z` with contour lines at the data values specified in the monotonically increasing vector `v`